# How to implement some convenient methods (e.g., flat_map, flatten) on Option?

Tags: rust

It would be nice if Rust's `Option` provided some additional convenience methods like `Option#flatten` and `Option#flat_map`, where `flatten` would reduce an `<Option<Option<T>>` to `Option<T>`, and `flat_map` would work like `map`, but takes a method/closure that returns an `Option` and flattens it.

`flat_map` is pretty straightforward:

```
fn opt_flat_map< T, U, F: FnOnce(T) -> Option<U> >(opt: Option<T>, f: F) -> Option<U> {
  match opt {
    Some(x) => f(x),
    None => None
  }
}
```

`flatten` is more complex, and I don't really know how to go about defining it. It might look something like:

```
fn opt_flatten<T, U>(opt: Option<T>) -> Option<U> {
  match opt {
      Some( Some(x) ) => flatten_option( Some(x) ),
      _ => opt
  }
}
```

But that certainly doesn't work. Any thoughts?

Also, how would I go about implementing these methods on the `Option` enum, so that I can use them natively on an `Option` instance? I know I need to add the type signature in somewhere around `impl OptionExts for Option<T>`, but I'm at a loss...

Hope this makes sense and I apologize for my imprecise terminology--I'm brand new to Rust.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

These probably already exist, just as different names to what you expect. Check the [docs for Option](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#).

You'll see `flat_map` more normally as `and_then`:

```
let x = Some(1);
let y = x.and_then(|v| Some(v + 1));
```

The bigger way of doing what you want is to declare a *trait* with the methods you want, then implement it for `Option`:

```
trait MyThings {
    fn more_optional(self) -> Option<Self>;
}

impl<T> MyThings for Option<T> {
    fn more_optional(self) -> Option<Option<T>> {
        Some(self)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let x = Some(1);
    let y = x.more_optional();
    println!("{:?}", y);
}
```

For `flatten`, I'd probably write:

```
fn flatten<T>(opt: Option<Option<T>>) -> Option<T> {
    match opt {
        None => None,
        Some(v) => v,
    }
}

fn main() {
    let x = Some(Some(1));
    let y = flatten(x);
    println!("{:?}", y);
}
```

But if you wanted a trait:

```
trait MyThings<T> {
    fn flatten(self) -> Option<T>;
}

impl<T> MyThings<T> for Option<Option<T>> {
    fn flatten(self) -> Option<T> {
        match self {
            None => None,
            Some(v) => v,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let x = Some(Some(1));
    let y = x.flatten();
    println!("{:?}", y);
}
```

> Would there be a way to allow flatten to arbitrary depth

See [How do I unwrap an arbitrary number of nested Option types?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52453180/155423)

Comment: awesome, thanks so much for the examples and the pointer to `and_then`, which is exactly what I wanted as `flat_map`. Would there be a way to allow `flatten` to arbitrary depth, e.g., for `Some(Some(Some(Some(3))))`, or would we have to implement traits for each level?

Comment: @kardeiz that's an interesting question. To my knowledge, there's no way of dealing with arbitrary nesting of types. I'd suggest opening a new question, as I'd like to see the answer myself. ^_^

Comment: @Shepmaster I'm pretty sure that this would require [negative bounds](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/586) to implement, since you would need a trait that is implemented for all types, but treated specially for `Option`s.

Comment: I also had trouble finding flatmap, that's why there's a pull request for including it in the documentation of `and_then`: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/22111

Answer (score 7):

```
fn flatten<T>(x: Option<Option<T>>) -> Option<T> {
    x.unwrap_or(None)
}
```

In my case, I was dealing with an `Option`-returning method in `unwrap_or_else` and forgot about plain `or_else` method.