# What's the idiomatic way to handle multiple `Option<T>` in Rust?

Tags: rust, option-type, monads

Since I'm fairly new to Rust, I need guidance on how error handling is done idiomatically. I find the error-handling boilerplate really annoying.

I'm stuck with multiple `Option<T>`s. It's too verbose to handle each `None` case manually.

In Haskell, for example, you can chain optional value (`Maybe`) operations with a variety of operators: `fmap`, `<*>`, `>>=`, etc.:

```hs
f x = x * x
g x = x ++ x
main = print $ g <$> show <$> f <$> Just 2
```

The same looks impossible in Rust. I'm trying to parse a two-character card string into a struct `Card`:

```
const FACES: &'static str = "23456789TJQKA";
const SUITS: &'static str = "CDHS";
enum Face { /* ... */ }
enum Suit { C, D, H, S }
struct Card {
    face: Face,
    suit: Suit
}
impl FromStr for Card {
    type Err = ();
    fn from_str(x: &str) -> Result<Self, Self::Err> {
        let mut xs = x.chars();
        let a = chain(xs.next(), |x| FACES.find(x), Face::from_usize);
        let b = chain(xs.next(), |x| SUITS.find(x), Suit::from_usize);
        if let (Some(face), Some(suit)) = (a, b) {
            Ok(Card::new(face, suit))
        } else {
            Err(())
        }
    }
}
```

This code would look like this in Haskell:

```hs
import Data.List (elemIndex)
x = Just 'C'
suits = "CDHS"
data Suit = C | D | H | S deriving Show
fromInt 0 = C
find = flip elemIndex
main = print $ x >>= find suits >>= return . fromInt
```

Thanks to the chaining via `>>=` Haskell makes it possible (and easy!) to manipulate the inner value of a monad. In order to achieve something close to that I had to write the `chain` function, which seems strongly unidiomatic:

```
fn join<T>(x: Option<Option<T>>) -> Option<T> {
    if let Some(y) = x {
        y
    } else {
        None
    }
}

fn bind<A, B, F>(x: Option<A>, f: F) -> Option<B>
where
    F: FnOnce(A) -> Option<B>,
{
    join(x.map(f))
}

fn chain<A, B, C, F, G>(x: Option<A>, f: F, g: G) -> Option<C>
where
    F: FnOnce(A) -> Option<B>,
    G: FnOnce(B) -> Option<C>,
{
    bind(bind(x, f), g)
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As mentioned, [`Option`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html) and [`Result`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html) have *tons* of utility methods on them. Additionally, the try operator (`?`) can also be used for the extremely common case of "return the failure or unwrap the result"

I'd implement `FromStr` for `Face` and `Suit`. Your code would then look like:

```
impl FromStr for Card {
    type Err = ();

    fn from_str(s: &str) -> Result<Self, Self::Err> {
        let face = s[0..1].parse()?;
        let suit = s[1..2].parse()?;

        Ok(Card { face, suit })
    }
}
```

If you didn't / couldn't, you can use the existing methods on `Option`. You didn't define `Foo::from_usize`, so I assume to returns `Foo`, so it would use `map`:

```
fn from_str(s: &str) -> Result<Self, Self::Err> {
    let mut c = s.chars();

    let face = c
        .next()
        .and_then(|c| FACES.find(c))
        .map(Face::from_usize)
        .ok_or(())?;
    let suit = c
        .next()
        .and_then(|c| SUITS.find(c))
        .map(Suit::from_usize)
        .ok_or(())?;

    Ok(Card { face, suit })
}
```

- [`Option::and_then`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.and_then)
- [`Option::map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.map)
- [`Option::ok_or`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.ok_or)

Both of these paths allow you to have *useful* errors, such as an enum that lets you know if the suit / face was missing / invalid. An error type of `()` is useless to consumers.

You could also define `Suit::from_char` and `Face::from_char` and not leak the implementation of the array out.

Putting it all together:

```
impl Suit {
    fn from_char(c: char) -> Option<Self> {
        use Suit::*;

        [('c', C), ('d', D), ('h', H), ('s', S)]
            .iter()
            .cloned()
            .find(|&(cc, _)| cc == c)
            .map(|(_, s)| s)
    }
}

enum Error {
    MissingFace,
    MissingSuit,
    InvalidFace,
    InvalidSuit,
}

impl FromStr for Card {
    type Err = Error;

    fn from_str(x: &str) -> Result<Self, Self::Err> {
        use Error::*;

        let mut xs = x.chars();

        let face = xs.next().ok_or(MissingFace)?;
        let face = Face::from_char(face).ok_or(InvalidFace)?;
        let suit = xs.next().ok_or(MissingSuit)?;
        let suit = Suit::from_char(suit).ok_or(InvalidSuit)?;

        Ok(Card { face, suit })
    }
}
```

---

```
fn join<T>(x: Option<Option<T>>) -> Option<T>
```

This is `x.and_then(|y| y)`

```
fn bind<A, B, F>(x: Option<A>, f: F) -> Option<B>
where
    F: FnOnce(A) -> Option<B>,
```

This is `x.and_then(f)`

```
fn chain<A, B, C, F, G>(x: Option<A>, f: F, g: G) -> Option<C>
where
    F: FnOnce(A) -> Option<B>,
    G: FnOnce(B) -> Option<C>,
```

This is `x.and_then(f).and_then(g)`

See also:

- [How to implement some convenient methods (e.g., flat_map, flatten) on Option?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28566531/155423)

Answer (score 12):

It seems like you want [`Option::and_then`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.and_then):

```rust
pub fn and_then<U, F>(self, f: F) -> Option<U> 
where
    F: FnOnce(T) -> Option<U>
```

Examples:

```rust
fn sq(x: u32) -> Option<u32> { Some(x * x) }
fn nope(_: u32) -> Option<u32> { None }

assert_eq!(Some(2).and_then(sq).and_then(sq), Some(16));
assert_eq!(Some(2).and_then(sq).and_then(nope), None);
assert_eq!(Some(2).and_then(nope).and_then(sq), None);
assert_eq!(None.and_then(sq).and_then(sq), None);
```

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the other answers, you can also take a look at the monadic expression crates like [mdo](https://crates.io/crates/mdo) or [map_for](https://crates.io/crates/map_for). For example with `map_for`:

```
fn from_str(x: &str) -> Result<Self, Self::Err> {
    let mut xs = x.chars();
    map_for!{
        ax <- xs.next();
        f  <- FACES.find(ax);
        a  <- Face::from_usize(f);
        bx <- xs.next();
        s  <- SUITS.find(bx);
        b  <- Suit::from_usize (s);
        => Card::new(a, b) }
    .ok_or(Err(()))
}
```

Full disclosure: I am the author of the `map_for` crate.

Answer (score 0):

`Maybe`-monadic chaining in Rust's `Result` is accomplished by [the `try!` macro](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.17.0/book/error-handling.html#the-try-macro). Should look something like

```
fn from_str(x: &str) -> Result<Self, Self::Err> {
    let mut xs = x.chars();
    let a = try!(chain(xs.next(), |x| FACES.find(x), Face::from_usize));
    let b = try!(chain(xs.next(), |x| SUITS.find(x), Suit::from_usize));
    Ok(Card::new(face, suit))
}
```

Comment: Now that `?` has been stabilized, I think `try!` is on its way out. `let a = chain(xs.next(), |x| FACES.find(x), Face::from_usize)?;` looks a bit better.

Comment: Interesting. Is that basically syntactic sugar for the old `try!`?

Comment: @leftaroundabout it's better, actually, as it's powered by the [`Try` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Try.html) so it's more flexible. For example, it works for `Option` and when it's stabilized it will be usable for user types.