# How do I check if both variables are both Some?

Tags: rust

I am confused about the `Some(T)` keyword.

I want to check for two variables, if the value is defined (not `None`). If that is the case, the value of this variables is processed.

I know the `match` pattern which works like this:

```
match value {
    Some(val) => println!("{}", val),
    None => return false,
}
```

If I use this pattern, it will get very messy:

```
match param {
    Some(par) => {
        match value {
            Some(val) => {
                //process
            },

            None => return false,
        }
    },

    None => return false,
}
```

This can't be the right solution.

The is a possibility, to ask if the param and value `is_some()` That would effect code like that:

```
if param.is_some() && value.is_some() {
    //process
}
```

But if I do it like that, I always have to unwrap `param` and `value` to access the values.

I thought about something like this to avoid that. But this code does not work:

```
if param == Some(par) && value == Some(val) {
    //process
}
```

The idea is that the values are accessible by `par` and `val` like they are in the `match` version.

Is there any solution to do something like this?

Comment: Did you already see `if let Some(T)`? https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch06-03-if-let.html It's useful when you just need value and "ignore" `None` value.

Comment: Nitpick: `Some` isn't a keyword in Rust. The language automatically pulls parts of the standard library into scope: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/prelude/index.html and `std::option::Option::{Some, None}` is part of that list.

Comment: Thank you both of you good to know.

Comment: See also [What's the idiomatic way to handle multiple `Option<T>` in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50731439/155423)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If I have several `Option` values to match, I match on a tuple of the values:

```rust
enum Color {
    Red,
    Blue,
    Green,
}

fn foo(a: Option<Color>, b: Option<i32>) {
    match (a, b) {
        (Some(Color::Blue), Some(n)) if n > 10 => println!("Blue large number"),
        (Some(Color::Red), _) => println!("Red number"),
        _ => (),
    }
}

fn main() {
    foo(Some(Color::Blue), None);
    foo(Some(Color::Blue), Some(20));
}
```

This allows me to match the combinations that are interesting, and discard the rest (or return false, if that is what you want to do).

Answer (score 8):

If your function is processing multiple `Option` values, and would like to discard them if they're not `Some`, your function could return an `Option` itself:

```rust
fn foo(param: Option<usize>, value: Option<usize>) -> Option<usize> {
    let result = param? + value?;
    Some(result)
}
```

This will short-circuit the function in case there's a `None` value stored in either `param` or `value`.

Please read [the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/error-handling-and-panics/the-question-mark-operator-for-easier-error-handling.html) for more information on the `?` operator.

If your function can't return an `Option`, you can still get away with destructuring using `if let` or `match`:

```rust
let x = if let (Some(p), Some(v)) = (param, value) {
    p + v
} else {
    return 0;
}
```

```rust
let x = match (param, value) {
    (Some(p), Some(v)) => p + v,
    (Some(p), _) => p,
    (_, Some(v) => v,
    _ => return 0,
}
```

---

- Please read [What is this question mark operator about?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42917566/what-is-this-question-mark-operator-about) for more information on the `?` operator
- Please read [this chapter in Rust by Example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/rust-by-example/flow_control/match/destructuring.html) for more information on destructuring multiple things at once

Answer (score 2):

There's a couple more alternatives not yet listed:

If you're willing to use experimental features (and hence the nightly compiler) you can use a try block as an alternative of extracting a function.

```
#![feature(try_blocks)]

fn main() {
    let par: Option<f32> = Some(1.0f32);
    let value: Option<f32> = Some(2.0f32);

    let x: Option<f32> = try { par? + value? };

    println!("{:?}", x);
}
```

Another alternative is to use `map` which only applies if the value is not None

```
let x: Option<f32> = par.map(|p| value.map(|v| p + v));
```