# Rust skip loop on "None" else move forward with computation

Tags: rust, idioms

I have a nested loop where I want to check if a certain condition holds on a table of `usize` values. However, the table may only be partially filled -- so it is actually a table of `Option<usize>` variables. When at least one of the values is missing, I do not consider the condition to be violated, and therefore want to continue on with the next set of values.

Currently I do it as follows:

```
for i in 0..n {
    for j in 0..n {
        for k in 0..n {
            let v_ij = match table[i][j] {
                None => { continue; },
                Some(val) => { val }
            };

            let v_jk = match table[j][k] {
                None => { continue; },
                Some(val) => { val }
            };

            let res_left = match table[v_ij][k] {
                None => { continue; },
                Some(val) => { val }
            };

            let res_right = match table[i][v_jk] {
                None => { continue; },
                Some(val) => { val }
            };

            if res_left != res_right {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(For context: the computation is checking whether a partial magma is associative, but this is not important for the question.)

Is there an idiomatic way to replace all these matches? In Haskell, using the Maybe monad, I believe I could wrap this piece of code up into a `do` block, so that `None` values are automatically propagated. I tried using `table[i][j].unwrap_or({continue;})` but this evaluates the `continue` greedily; using `table[i][j].unwrap_or_else({continue;})` gives a syntax error.

Comment: `match (a, b, c, d, e) { (Some(a), Some(b), ...) => {}, None => {} }`

Comment: @Stargateur, that makes it a bit shorter, but note that the third and fourth `match` blocks use the outputs of the first two as indices into `table`. I would still be left with two blocks (and in fact with three because the top block should be one for loop "up").

Comment: `table[i][j].and_then(|v_ij| table[j][k].and_then(|v_jk| ...` https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.and_then

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the idiomatic way to handle multiple \`Option<T>\` in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50731439/whats-the-idiomatic-way-to-handle-multiple-optiont-in-rust)

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55755552/what-is-the-rust-equivalent-to-a-try-catch-statement/55758013#55758013

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In such a case, to limit repetition and to improve clarity, I would probably use a macro:

```
macro_rules! unwrap_or_continue {
    ($opt: expr) => {
        match $opt {
            Some(v) => v,
            None => {continue;}
        }
    }
}
```

There is [loop_unwrap](https://docs.rs/loop_unwrap/0.2.0/loop_unwrap/macro.unwrap_continue.html) crate that implement something similar but more complex.

Thus each of your test would be reduced:

```
for i in 0..n {
    for j in 0..n {
        for k in 0..n {
            let v_ij = unwrap_or_continue!(table[i][j]);
            let v_jk = unwrap_or_continue!(table[j][k]);
            let res_left = unwrap_or_continue!(table[v_ij][k]);
            let res_right = unwrap_or_continue!(table[i][v_jk]);
            if res_left != res_right {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Using the `?` operator on options to do the `continue` for you, and [itertools](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.10.0/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.permutations) to build the iterator, you could take a functional approach:

```
use itertools::Itertools;

let has_false = (0..n)
    .permutations(3)
    .filter_map(|v| {
        let (i, j, k) = (v[0], v[1], v[2]);
        let v_ij = table[i][j]?;
        let v_jk = table[j][k]?;
        Some((table[v_ij][k]?, table[i][v_jk]?))
    })
    .any(|(res_left, res_right)| res_left != res_right);
```