# What is an idiomatic way to return Ok(None) if one of multiple Options is None, otherwise unwrap all Options?

Tags: rust

I have a function that returns `Result<Option<[type]>>` on an `Input` type:

```
pub struct Input {
    a: Option<i32>,
    b: Option<i32>,
    c: Option<i32>,
}
```

For each field in `input` if the value is `None`, the function will immediately return `Ok(None)` and if there's a value, the function will unwrap it and proceed with further logic:

```
fn process(input: Input) -> std::io::Result<Option<i32>> {
    let a = match input.a {
        Some(a) => a,
        None => return Ok(None),
    };
    // the same for b and c...
    todo!()
}
```

The same pattern in repeated for all the fields in the input type. Is there a prettier way to express this?

Comment: I needed something similar when iterating over files in a directory, where I'd use `?` to handle errors (by stopping the iteration that collects into `Result<Vec<T>>`) but would have also likeed to use `?` on options to skip some files (without stopping the iteration, e.g. using `filter_map`). Unfortunately I don't think you can convince `?` to return `Ok(...)`.

Comment: [What's the idiomatic way to handle multiple `Option<T>` in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50731439/155423)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use a `if let` to assign all variables at once and return `Ok(None)` in the `else` branch:

```rust
fn process(input: Input) -> std::io::Result<Option<i32>> {
    if let (Some(a), Some(b), Some(c)) = (input.a, input.b, input.c) {
        todo!();
    } else {
        return Ok(None)
    }
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=bcc55ccd0b54d3ff2682d3ecf7a39389)

Edit: Or, even more concise (thanks to Dietrich Epp for the suggestion!):

```rust
fn process(input: Input) -> std::io::Result<Option<i32>> {
    if let Input {
        a: Some(a),
        b: Some(b),
        c: Some(c),
    } = input
    {
        todo!();
    } else {
        return Ok(None);
    }
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=de000d19c31ba33d825f53ef8e29c7be)

Comment: Is there way to have some output generated within `if let` block and use it afterwards within the function, or I am constrained to move my whole function logic within the `if let` block?

Comment: @NasifImtiazOhi `if let` is (as most control flow structures in Rust) an expression. If you end the `if let` body with an expression, this is also the result of the `if let` expression. An [example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=60bb4b5be8a1cbcf03c3144db74deab7) will probably make this more clear.

Comment: @NasifImtiazOhi You can transform original match to use a tuple in the same way: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=05b4ba388d745eeae1d93f4427350a19

Comment: (Of course, this won't work if your options aren't neatly available in a struct, but you need to calculate them with code in-between, but for your case it should work nicely.)

Answer (score 4):

On nightly, you can use [`try_blocks`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/unstable-book/language-features/try-blocks.html):

```rust
#![feature(try_blocks)]

let x: Option<_> = try { (input.a?, input.b?, input.c?) };

let (a, b, c) = match x {
    Some((a, b, c)) => (a, b, c),
    None => return Ok(None),
};
```

A stable alternative is creating and immediately calling a closure, although it doesn't look as nice:

```rust
let x = (|| { Some((input.a?, input.b?, input.c?)) })();

let (a, b, c) = match x {
    Some((a, b, c)) => (a, b, c),
    None => return Ok(None),
};
```

Maybe the cleanest solution is [`Option::and_then`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.and_then) combined with the `?` operator:

```rust
let x = input.a.and_then(|a| Some((a, input.b?, input.c?)));

let (a, b, c) = match x {
    Some((a, b, c)) => (a, b, c),
    None => return Ok(None),
};
```

You can also use [`Option::zip`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.zip), although you'll end up with nested tuples:

```rust
let x = input.a.zip(input.b).zip(input.c);

let (a, b, c) = match x {
    Some(((a, b), c)) => (a, b, c),
    None => return Ok(None),
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility (but @sk_pleasant's version is way cleaner). [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=38eb192f547a132c187dd0ebc1e8cbf2)

```
fn main() {
    let inp = Input { a:Some(1), b:Some(2), c:Some(3) };
    let unwrapped = 
        inp.a.map_or(None, |a| 
            inp.b.map_or(None, |b| 
                inp.c.map_or(None, |c| Some((a, b, c)))));   
    match unwrapped {
        Some((a, b, c)) => println!("{} {} {}", a, b, c),
        None => println!("None"), // return Ok(None);
    }
}
```