# How can I flatten nested Results?

Tags: error-handling, rust, flatten

I'm working with a third-party library that provides tree-based data structures that I have to use "as is". The API returns `Result<T, Error>`. I have to make some sequential calls and convert the error to my  application's internal error.

```rust
use std::error::Error;
use std::fmt;

pub struct Tree {
    branches: Vec<Tree>,
}

impl Tree {
    pub fn new(branches: Vec<Tree>) -> Self {
        Tree { branches }
    }

    pub fn get_branch(&self, id: usize) -> Result<&Tree, TreeError> {
        self.branches.get(id).ok_or(TreeError {
            description: "not found".to_string(),
        })
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct TreeError {
    description: String,
}

impl Error for TreeError {
    fn description(&self) -> &str {
        self.description.as_str()
    }
}

impl fmt::Display for TreeError {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        self.description.fmt(f)
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct MyAwesomeError {
    description: String,
}

impl MyAwesomeError {
    pub fn from<T: fmt::Debug>(t: T) -> Self {
        MyAwesomeError {
            description: format!("{:?}", t),
        }
    }
}

impl Error for MyAwesomeError {
    fn description(&self) -> &str {
        &self.description
    }
}

impl fmt::Display for MyAwesomeError {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        self.description.fmt(f)
    }
}
```

If I write this code:

```rust
pub fn take_first_three_times(tree: &Tree) -> Result<&Tree, MyAwesomeError> {
    let result = tree
        .get_branch(0)
        .map(|r| r.get_branch(0))
        .map(|r| r.map(|r| r.get_branch(0)));
    //    ...
}
```

The type of `result` will be `Result<Result<Result<Tree, TreeError>, TreeError>, TreeError>`. I don't want to process errors by cascades of `match`.

I can write an internal function that adjusts the API's interface and processes the error in the level of base function:

```rust
fn take_first_three_times_internal(tree: &Tree) -> Result<&Tree, TreeError> {
    tree.get_branch(0)?.get_branch(0)?.get_branch(0)
}

pub fn take_first_three_times(tree: &Tree) -> Result<&Tree, MyAwesomeError> {
    take_first_three_times_internal(tree).map_err(MyAwesomeError::from)
}
```

How can I achieve this without an additional function?

Comment: See also [How do I unwrap an arbitrary number of nested Option types?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52453180/155423)

Comment: Thankfully, this exists now: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.flatten. Currently, nightly only

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This is an example of issue, when you're working with various wrappers like `Option` in functional programming. In functional programming there are such called 'pure' functions, that instead of changing some state (global variables, out parameters) only rely on input parameters and only return their result as return value without any side effects. It makes programs much more predictable and safe, but it introduced some inconveniences.

Imagine we have `let x = Some(2)` and some function `f(x: i32) -> Option<f32>`. When you use `map` to apply that `f` to `x`, you'll get nested `Option<Option<f32>>`, which is the same issue that you got.

But in the world of functional programming (Rust was inspired with their ideas a lot and supports a lot of typical 'functional' features) they came up with solution: monads.

We can show `map` a signature like `(A<T>, FnOnce(T)->U) -> A<U>` where `A` is something like wrapper type, such as `Option` or `Result`. In FP such types are called functors. But there is an advanced version of it, called a monad. It has, besides the `map` function, one more similar function in its interface, traditionally called `bind` with signature like `(A<T>, FnOnce(T) -> A<U>) -> A<U>`. More details [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44965/what-is-a-monad).

In fact, Rust's `Option` and `Result` is not only a functor, but a monad too. That `bind` in our case is implemented as [`and_then`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.and_then) method. For example, you could use it in our example like this: `x.and_then(f)`, and get simple `Option<f32>` as a result. So instead of a `.map` chain you could have `.and_then` chain that will act very similar, but there will be no nested results.

Comment: Its cool that `Result` is a propper monad. It makes some things much easier, however, `and_then` works well for mapping from `Ok` to `Err` but not from `Err` to `Ok`. it only runs the function on `Ok` branches

Answer (score 1):

Combining `and_then` and using the `?` operator, my solution is as follows:

```rs
pub fn take_first_three_times(tree: &Tree) -> Result<&Tree, MyAwesomeError> {
    tree.get_branch(0).and_then(|first| {
        first.get_branch(0)?.get_branch(0)
    }).map_err(MyAwesomeError::from)
}
```

really, this just replaces the internal function with a FnOnce closure

Answer (score 1):

I personally solved it by making a custom trait that allows me to flatten any result where the error of the inner result can be converted into the outer result.

```rust
/// flattens a nested result, converting the inner error into the outer error
pub trait FlattenResult<V, OuterError, InnerError>
where
    InnerError: Into<OuterError>,
    Result<V, OuterError>: From<ResultWrapper<V, InnerError>>,
{
    fn flatten_result(self) -> Result<V, OuterError>;
}

impl<V, OuterError, InnerError> FlattenResult<V, OuterError, InnerError>
    for Result<Result<V, InnerError>, OuterError>
where
    OuterError: From<InnerError>,
{
    fn flatten_result(self) -> Result<V, OuterError> {
        match self {
            Ok(inner) => ResultWrapper(inner).into(),
            Err(err) => Err(err),
        }
    }
}

/// A wrapper around Result, to be able to have the custom From implementation
pub struct ResultWrapper<V, E>(Result<V, E>);

impl<V, InnerError, OuterError> From<ResultWrapper<V, InnerError>>
    for Result<V, OuterError>
where
    OuterError: From<InnerError>,
{
    fn from(value: ResultWrapper<V, InnerError>) -> Self {
        match value.0 {
            Ok(inner) => Ok(inner),
            Err(err) => Err(err.into()),
        }
    }
}
```

You can see [here](https://codeberg.org/OpenThingies/openmood-server/src/commit/21b9e18d2204ae5e4336e65e1742302efbdafe34/src/error.rs#L63-L118) how to use it

I left out document comments from this example, those can also be found in that same file.

The way this works is quite simple. For any `Result<Result<V, InnerError>, OuterError>` where `InnerError` can be converted into `OuterError`, simply coerce the inner error into the outer error.

The downside to this approach is the fact that you do have to import the trait each time you wanna use `flatten_result`. Personally I found that fine, but obviously YMMV