# How can I alter the behavior of a function based on the return type of a closure passed as an argument?

Tags: rust, closures

I have a function that returns the result of a curried function:

```
async fn runit<F, Fut, Ret>(cb: F) -> Result<Ret, MyError>
where
    F: FnOnce() -> Fut,
    Fut: Future<Output = Ret>,
{
    Ok(cb().await)
}
```

Sometimes `F` may return a `Result<Ret, MyError>`, requiring the caller to unwrap the returned value twice. Is there a way I can write this such that the function automatically detects whether `F` already returns the right type and avoids the call to `Ok`?

Comment: Why not just return `Ret`? `async fn runit<F, Fut, Ret>(cb: F) -> Ret`

Comment: @IbraheemAhmed The real `runit` probably does things other than invoking `cb()` which can fail with `MyError`.

Comment: See also [How do I unwrap an arbitrary number of nested Option types?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52453180/155423); [How can I flatten nested Results?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59028327/155423)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to use a trait with separate blanket implementations for `Result` and other types. Something like:

```
pub trait IntoResult<T, E> {
    fn into_result(self) -> Result<T, E>;
}

impl<T, E> IntoResult<T, E> for Result<T, E> {
    fn into_result(self) -> Result<T, E> {
        self
    }
}

impl<T, E> IntoResult<T, E> for T {
    fn into_result(self) -> Result<T, E> {
        Ok(self)
    }
}
```

Then you can implement `runit` to call `into_result()`:

```
async fn runit<F, Fut, Ret, RawRet>(cb: F) -> Result<Ret, MyError>
where
    F: FnOnce() -> Fut,
    Fut: Future<Output = RawRet>,
    RawRet: IntoResult<Ret, MyError>,
{
    cb().await.into_result()
}
```

Now Rust will be able to infer `Ret` that satisfies the `IntoResult` trait, effectively eliminating the inner `Result`:

```
// one unwrap needed for Result<usize, MyError>
let _x: usize = runit(|| async { 1 }).await.unwrap();
// two unwraps needed because closure returns Result whose error is not MyError
let _y: usize = runit(|| async { Ok::<_, std::io::Error>(1usize) })
    .await
    .unwrap()
    .unwrap();
// one unwrap enough because closure returns Result<usize, MyError>
let _z: usize = runit(|| async { Ok::<_, MyError>(1usize) }).await.unwrap();
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e0ad381588163e8f5c0c81ef9b01175a)

Before using this in production, I suggest being very careful with this kind of "cleverness". While it looks really nice when it works, it can complicate the signatures of functions and sometimes it can require type hints that would otherwise not be necessary. It is often simpler to use something like `anyhow::Error` to coalesce results of incompatible errors into one result.

Comment: I'm surprised this works as I would have thought that `T` in the second `impl` could have be `Result<Tprime, E>`, causing an overlapping implementation issue that requires specialization.

Comment: @Shepmaster My thoughts precisely (before I saw this pattern somewhere). I thought that it works because `Result` is defined outside the crate or is special-cased by orphan rule, but that doesn't appear to be the case because it compiles if you [switch to a locally defined type](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f5df07975bb392143b79752690ac9c8d). The remaining explanation is that it somehow hits generics in a way that make it ok - or even a compiler bug?

Comment: It's got to be related to [the changes in 1.41](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2020/01/30/Rust-1.41.0.html), but I'll still need to dig deeper to understand.

Comment: @Shepmaster For what it's worth, it [compiles with 1.40](https://rust.godbolt.org/z/c6eT9T) (also [with local Result](https://rust.godbolt.org/z/zGfvvs)), so I guess that rules out the 1.41 changes.

Comment: Asking around [in Zulip](https://rust-lang.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/122651-general/topic/unexpectedly.20non-overlapping.20blanket.20implementaions), it was pointed out that by adding generics to the trait definition, we actually create _multiple traits_, so there's no overlap possible. If the generics were removed or turned into associated types, then there would be multiple implementations of the same trait for the same type.

Comment: @Shepmaster That makes sense. In other words, it's not possible to find `T` and `E` such that `IntoResult<T, E>` is implemented for both `T` and `Result<T, E>`.